# Handle concurrent access inside Power Apps for SubmitForm() & Patch()

Tags: concurrency, sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am working on a Canvas application which is connected to SharePoint online lists and libraries. and i mainly use these methods to edit data:-

1. SubmitForm()
2. Patch()

currently there is not any mechanism to handle concurrent access, where currently if 2 users access an item to edit it, they both can save the form and the last user who submit the form will have his/her data inside the SharePoint lists. so is there a way to allow power apps canvas application to handle concurrent access, so it will show an error to the second user that the data he/she is viewing has been modified since it was retrieved?

I am thinking of doing a check before submitting or patching an item, where i will check the current item modified date with the modified date currently on SharePoint (by doing a LookUp()), if the modified are the same i will proceed with the submission if not then this mean that the item was modified since it was viewed... i am trying to avoid this manual method, and find a way to allow power apps to do this out of the box? is there a way?

for example, in Entity framework (where i come from), we can implement optimistic locking by submitting a timestamp with the update request and the data base will raise an exception if the timestamp does not match the one inside the database.

Thanks

Comment: In order to better help you solve your problem, you can describe your problem with desired results in more detail.